# Debugger <panic> on MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

I was updating my iTunes and left my MacBook Air open to finish and restart. When I came back a few hours later my Mac was showing the grey apple screen with the apple and then black lines of code down the left side of the screen. It said debugger "Unable to find driver for this platform: ..." And then kernel version Darwin kernel version kernel UUID kernel slide and kernel text base.

I have no idea what has happened. I thought it was a kernel panic but my screen looks nothing like any screen that shows up when I research kernel panic. I've rebooted it in safe mode and just normally about 20 times. Nothing is changing it.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Did this happen after a system update perhaps?
It seems that a lot of people have similar problems after the "Thunderbolt update" from Apple.

check [this](http://discussions.apple.com/thread/4021315?tstart=0)  thread

Comment: You're welcome. If you think that this has helped you please accept it it as a solution..

Comment: Could you please add which MacOS X update does contain this faulty Thunderbolt driver, so as to avoid anyone else to make this dangerous Update?

Comment: from what i understand apple has pulled that update back. But if you had downloaded it and hadn't installed it immediately (like i use to do most of the times...) that could pose a problem. the only info about that update i can offer is that is called "Thunderbolt update (for gig adaptor)"